# Autodesk Construction Cloud - Upload and get last modified time

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management, autodesk-construction-cloud

i am writing app that is processing files from ACC docs based on the last modified date of the file. The issue i am having is that sometimes i need to modify the files and upload a new version through the API, which causes the last modified time to change on the file but this could be any amount of time after the API call to create the new version. Is there an API i can call in a loop to get when the upload is complete and the last modified time has been set in ACC?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to address this is through [Webhooks API](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/developers_guide/overview/).

Please note that you can take advantage of the [Data Management events](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/data_management_events/) in order to react to folder or version modification. This will notify your app once the respective event gets triggered.

Also, if you need to perform any task only after the design is uploaded **and translated**, you can achieve that with the [extraction.finished event](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/webhooks/v1/reference/events/model_derivative_events/extraction.finished/), as explained at https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/webhook-now-supports-translation-progress-bim360-or-acc-files

### Update

If you can't handle that with Webhooks, there's the way bellow:

Once you [update](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/#step-8-update-the-version-of-a-file) or [create](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/#step-7-create-the-first-version-of-the-uploaded-file) the version of the file, you can use its `urn` to check the translation progress through [GET manifest](https://aps.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/manifest/urn-manifest-GET/) endpoint.
In this case, you'll need to make this request in a loop until the progress is complete.

Comment: Thanks for the info Joao, ideally this would be the solution but due to infrastructure constraints on this project, i am not using Webhooks, is there any other way?

Comment: Got it!
Answer updated!